# How to restrict Forge App to read-only access?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have created a Forge app to access our files on BIM 360, with the goal to read data or download files.
Is there a way to limit the app’s rights to read-only whatever data scope is set in the authentication Post request ?
We havent found the answer in the following documents :

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/api-key-security-considerations
Thanks

Also registered as support case 16567046 which redirected us to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your user only have read scope to your BIM360 files within this Forge App. The current solution is to provide your BIM360 user read only access_token, you can achieve this by providing “data:read” 
scope while getting the authorize(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/), and with this scope of token, you BIM360 user could only read his data.

Hope it helps, and if this doesn't work as you expected, let us know.

Comment: The App is not intended to be used by users, but for data exchange with other systems. It doesnt't need write access because the App only read files from BIM 360.
So for security reason we would prefer to restrict the app's rights to read-only if possible.

Comment: It's similar, you can use the "data:read" only scope while get your 2 legged token by https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/, and this will provide you read only access to the data.